# Select All Items in asp.net CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist, selectall

ASP.NET and C#.

I'd like to have a CheckboxList with a "Select All" item.

- When this particular item is
  selected, all others will be selected
  too.
- When selection is removed from
  this item, so too will it be from all
  others items.
- Checking/Unchecking of
  any other items will only have an
  effect on that particular item
  regardless of the selection state of
  "Select All" item.

I am looking for a jquery solution to this.

Here is the databinding code in my codebehind:

```
IList<Central> Centrals = new CentralProvider().GetAllCentralsAsList();
Centrals.Insert(0, new Central(){Central_ID = 999, Central_Name = "Select All"});
CentralChecks.DataSource = Centrals;
CentralChecks.DataTextField = "Central_Name";
CentralChecks.DataValueField = "Central_ID";
CentralChecks.DataBind();
```

And here is the markup:

```
<div class="CentralDiv" id="CentralDiv">
    <h2>Centrals:</h2>
    <span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="CentralTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="textbox">Centrals</asp:TextBox>
        <img id="CentralArrow" src="images/down_arrow.jpg" style="margin-left: -22px; margin-bottom: -5px" />
    </span>
    <div id="CentralEffect" class="ui-widget-content">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CentralChecks" runat="server" onclick="GetSelectedCentralValue();">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that there are multiple checkbox lists on the page, so any solution must keep this in mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like you could use for any of your checkbox lists, just add a cssclass of myCheckBoxList to each CheckBoxList control:

```
$('.myCheckBoxList :checkbox').eq(0).click(function() { 
    var toggle = this.checked;
    $('.myCheckBoxList :checkbox').attr("checked", toggle);
});
```

Comment: This is perfect - elegant and adaptable.  +1 and marked as answer.  Thank you.

Comment: I agree. Very simple to implement. Just need to insert the script after the checkboxlist is rendered.

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Product 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Product 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CssClass="myCheckBoxList">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Product 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Product 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: @pvaju896 please create a new question, you can then reference this question

Comment: @mdmullinax: +1 Brilliant. The only flaw is: *you can only have one of these controls on a page at a time as they will interfere with each other*.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all ListItems on click of Select All. And maintain a state flag to maintain whether all checkboxes are checked or not

```
if(boolAllChecked) {
    foreach (ListItem listItem in CentralChecks.Items)
    {
         listItem .Selected = false;
    }
}
else {
    foreach (ListItem listItem in CentralChecks.Items)
    {
         listItem .Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although this isn't a jquery solution

Answer (score 0):

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VTgGA/

code:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.attr('ref') != 'checkall'){
        $(".select-all").attr('checked',false);
    }
    else {
        //Select All
        var $checked = $this.is(':checked');
        $('input:checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked',$checked);
        })
        $(".select-all").attr('checked',$checked);
    }
})
```

this is what the html of the checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' ref='checkall' class='select-all'/>
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
```

Comment: How can I give only the first element in a CheckBoxList a particular ref or class value?

Comment: well u just need to make a seperate checkbox for ur select all item

Comment: I see you have answered a lot of PHP questions.  I'm not sure what your experience is with the CheckBoxList control in asp.net but as far as I'm aware, this cannot be done.  Perhaps you can offer a code sample to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Extending mdmullinax's brilliant answer, I came up with this generic solution for "select all" behavior that also unticks the "select all" (i.e. first) option if any other option is unticked and reticks the "select all" when all other items are ticked.

It also executes on window load as I inject it from ASP.Net server-side controls (which inject script in the head section of the page). Better to be safe than sorry :)

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        var cbs = $('.myCheckBoxList :checkbox');
        cbs.eq(0).click(function () {
            var toggle = this.checked;
            cbs.attr('checked', toggle);
        });
        cbs.slice(1).click(function () {
            if (!this.checked) {
                cbs.eq(0).attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                cbs.eq(0).attr('checked', cbs.slice(1).filter(':not(:checked)').length == 0);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic way of having a select all item in asp CheckBoxList with using jquery.
You can have as many as CheckBoxList controls on the form with the select all functionality.
you only need to make sure

1. Your CheckBoxList has **allowSelectAll** Class
2. You added a ListItem to your checkbox list to allow users to select
   All with the value of **All**

> chkBoxList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "All"));

you Only need the following code

```
<script>
    $('.allowSelectAll :checkbox[value=All]').click(function () {
        var toggle = this.checked;
        $(this).closest('.allowSelectAll').find(":checkbox").attr("checked", toggle);
    });
</script>
```

In the following code spinet I have 4 Checkbox lists

```
<div >
<label>Experience 1</label>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstExp1" runat="server"  CssClass="allowSelectAll">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<label>Experience 2</label>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstExp2" runat="server" CssClass="allowSelectAll">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<label>Experience 3</label>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstExp3" runat="server" CssClass="allowSelectAll">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<label>Location</label>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstLocation" runat="server" CssClass="allowSelectAll">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowReport" OnClick="btnShowReport_Click" Text="Show Report"/>
</div>
```