# Select All Items in asp.net CheckBoxList in Telerik's RadGrid's FormTemplate

Tags: jquery, telerik

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397184/select-all-items-in-asp-net-checkboxlist), bit the big difference is that the `CheckBoxList` is in the `FormTemplate` of a Telerk's `RadGrid`.

I tried this approaches, but they don't work:

[Check/Uncheck all Items in an ASP.NET CheckBox List using jQuery](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=236)

[Java Script for checkbox list in grid's editformsettings](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/java-script-for-checkbox-list-in-grid-s-editformsettings.aspx)

Here's my code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" ... >
   ...
   <MasterTableView ...>
      ...
      <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
         <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1"></EditColumn>
         <FormTemplate>
            <table class="edit-table-rad" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="0">
               ...
               <tr>
                  <td align="left" width="200px">
                     <b>Languages:</b><br />
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chbSelectAllLanguage" runat="server" 
                                   Text="Select All"
                                   ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblLanguage" runat="server" 
                                       DataSourceID="entityDataSourceLanguage"
                                       DataTextField="LanguageName"
                                       DataValueField="LanguageID"
                                       RepeatColumns="4">
                     </asp:CheckBoxList>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               ...
            </table>
         </FormTemplate>
      </EditFormSettings>
   </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

The examples above use jQuery to get the `CheckBox` and add a `click` function. But I can't get the `CheckBox`. I tried getting it by the ID and by a cssclass, but I think that the `CheckBox` in the RadGrid's `FormTemplate` is not in the DOM at `document.ready` time.

Is there a way to select/deselect all `CheckBoxList` items by selecting/deselecting the single `CheckBox`?

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

I can't find the HTML of the `FormTemplate` before I open the edit form. When the form is open, the HTML is this:

```
<tr>
<td width="200px" align="left">
    <b>Languages:</b>
    <br>
    <span class="chbSelectAllLanguage">
        <input id="chbSelectAllLanguage" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$rgSurvey$ctl00$ctl02$ctl04$chbSelectAllLanguage">
        <label for="chbSelectAllLanguage">Select All</label>
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <table id="ctl00_MainContent_rgSurvey_ctl00_ctl02_ctl04_cblLanguage" class="kipCheckBoxList">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                //the CheckBoxList generated data, like this:
                <td>
                    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_rgSurvey_ctl00_ctl02_ctl04_cblLanguage_0" type="checkbox" value="1" name="ctl00$MainContent$rgSurvey$ctl00$ctl02$ctl04$cblLanguage$0">
                    <label for="ctl00_MainContent_rgSurvey_ctl00_ctl02_ctl04_cblLanguage_0">English</label>
                </td>
                ...
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: The code the above generates will definately be ready on document load, so that isn't the issue. Could you please post the HTML this generates as it's easier to see what jQuery code will be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! The trick was to put the `<script>` tag inside an `<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock" runat="server">` tag, and then add this code to the `ItemDataBound` event od the `RadGrid`:

```
if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
{
   GridEditableItem geiItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
   CheckBox chbSelectAllLanguage = geiItem.FindControl("chbSelectAllLanguage") as CheckBox;
   CheckBoxList cblLanguage = geiItem.FindControl("cblLanguage") as CheckBoxList;
   chbSelectAllLanguage.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectDeselect('" + chbSelectAllLanguage.ClientID + "','" + cblLanguage.ClientID + "')");
}
```

Then the function for selectin/deselecting is like this:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function SelectDeselect(chk, chklst) {
         var isChecked = $('#' + chk).is(':checked');
         $("[id^=" + chklst + "]").each(function () {
             $(this).attr("checked", isChecked);
         });
      }
   </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```